# Is it possible to continue numbering after inserting a table?

Tags: mediawiki

I want my list to show up as:

```
1. Step 1
2. Step 2:
   <table>
3. Step 3
```

but it shows up as:

```
1. Step 1
2. Step 2:
<table>
1. Step 3
```

Code:

```
# Step 1
# Step 2:
:: {| ... |}
# Step 3
```

Is it possible to continue numbering after inserting a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using HTML markup, and the (<s>strictly speaking deprecated</s> [reintroduced](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html) in HTML5) `start` attibute. The `<ol>` tag, and other list tags, are among the few [allowed HTML tags](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:HTML_in_wikitext#Permitted_HTML) in the MediaWiki default setup.

```
*Argentina
*Brazil

{|
  ...
|}

<ol start=3>
  <li>China
  <li>Denmark
  <li>Egypt
</ol>
```

Or, as the TS points out, you can use HTML for the whole list, and insert the table inside the `<li>`:

```
<ol>
  <li>Argentina
  <li>Brazil

  {|
    <!-- insert table here -->
  |}

  </li><!-- Close this tag -->
  <li>China
  <li>Denmark
  <li>Egypt
</ol>
```

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind the `ul` tag you just added, @neverendingqs? To me it makes no sense semantically (and also, it would require a closing <li> tag). If it is just for spacing, maybe use CSS?

Comment: I totally overlooked the closing <li> tags. As for the `ul`, I was trying to insert a table of values as a subpoint (for me, it's a list of configuration names and values).